# How do I expand or reduce formulas depending on cell content

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a table consisting of several sheets. The table should be processed daily by several users at the same time. The main editing is done in Sheet1. Sheet2 consists only of a query and formulas.

Example Sheet 1:

- Sheet 1 consists of 2500 rows and 17 columns.

Starting with row 12 (row 11 is the header row. The rows above contain formula references), columns A, B are to be filled in by the user. The columns C-H contain various formulas (e.g. GoogleFinance queries). The columns G-M must be filled in again by the user. Finally, there are formulas in the columns N-Q again.

Goal: Automatic expansion / deletion of formulas in columns C-H and N-Q, depending on whether content has been added / removed in columns A and B. The deletion process should be performed line by line to also delete remaining user content in the columns G-M.

The sheet schould also be sortable.

Example Sheet 2:

- Sheet 2 consists of 1500 rows and 11 columns.

Starting with line 9 (line 9 is also the header line. The rows above contain formula references), the columns A-I are filled with results of a query (which is located in cell A9).  The query obtains certain contents from Sheet 1 and is dynamic. The columns J-K contain formulas.

Goal: Automatically extend / delete the formulas in the columns J-K, depending on whether content was added / removed in the columns A-I (by the query).

For extending, deleting and sorting I used the code examples below.

Unfortunately, the codes shown do not meet the requirements described in the constellation. I would therefore be very grateful for a better solution.

```
function fillDownFormulaTD(){

  Sheet = "sheet1";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(Sheet);
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var Rng1 = ss.getRange(1, 2, lr-1);

  ss.getRange("").setFormula('');
  ss.getRange("").copyTo(Rng1);         
}
```

---

```
function removeEmptyRows(){    
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Ticker-Datenbank');
  var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows(); 
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  sheet.deleteRows(lastRow+1, maxRows-lastRow-20);            
}
```

---

```
function Sortieren(){

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A11:Q11')
  var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().sort({column: 3, ascending: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('A11').activate();
 }
```

Comment: How many rows of data do you have? How long does it take for your spreadsheet to recalculate? How often is data being added or deleted? Are you describing a situation where the data is edited/deleted not just in one cell at a time, but potentially in many cells (i.e. a range over several rows? _I have a table consisting of several sheets_ Please describe how the table consisting of several sheet.

Comment: Have you considered using an `onEdit` trigger. It tells you the columnStart, columnEnd, rowStart and rowEnd. Why not use these coordinates to loop though several rows and test cells for add/deleted data?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I did some changes in my spreadsheet and therfore I editet the description. I hope the description is clear now in terms of functionality and workflow.

Comment: I can’t imagine why I didn’t ask this before... would you please share your spreadsheet, or a non-confidential version thereof.

Comment: Sure, here is the link to a copy with some sample entries.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QjAHsVQYUl-FYFqA0Aj7BmjnWAPPOd3_uCP7fiwiqII/edit?usp=sharing

In the copy, columns A and B are already prefilled. Columns I-N, on the other hand, contain only a few sample entries. However, in the official version these columns will be fully filled. In use, it will happen that entries are deleted from columns A and B or new entries are added. In these cases, the corresponding rows should be deleted or new formulas added.

At the moment the formulas reach the end of the table.

Comment: May I clarify the "Sheet1 Goal". **Logic#1:** if there is an edit in Column A or B (row#>=12), **AND** there is data in the edited cell (that is, the edit did not make the cell blank), then copy (or recopy) the formulas from row 12 Columns C-H and N-Q onto the edited row. **Logic#2:** if there is an edit in Column A or B (row#>=12), **AND** the edit has made the cell blank (the data was deleted), then delete the entire edited row. **Question:** Does this logic refer to sheet named "Geprüfte Ticker"?

Comment: May I clarify the "Sheet2 Goal".I noticed that there are several sheets with 11 columns (A-K), and "manual" formula in Columns J and I. **Question:** Does the reference to "Sheet2" apply to the various sheets named "WatchList and BlackList"?

Comment: You are very welcome to clarify the "Sheet1 Goal" and also the "Sheet2 Goal". To your question with regard to Sheet1: Correct, the described logic referes to the sheet named "Geprüfte Ticker". To your question with regard to Sheet2: Also correct. All the sheets called "Watchlist [""]", "Ready2Order" and "Blacklist" are copys of the sheet "Watchlist [Monat]" which I called here "Sheet2". However, the sheet "Blacklist" is a little reduced compared to the other copys.

Comment: I'm sorry. There is one more thing I forgot to say. The sheet called "Geprüfte Ticker" should also be sortable. Therefore I recorded and used a macro as you can see in the description above. It would be important to me that the sorting doesn't interfere with the work. I had solved this so far that I triggered the sorting by a time trigger, e.g. at night, when nobody is working on it. I would be very grateful for a better solution here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick solution for Sheet2 (an answer for Sheet#1 is in the works).

For Sheet2, rather than manually populate every row of Columns J and I with formula, use an arrayformula that will "automatically" expand/contract according to the rows with data.

1. Delete ALL the formula (cells that are blank and non-blank) for every row>9 in Column J and Column I.
2. In Cell J10, insert this formula
   `=arrayformula(IF($C10:$C="";"";HYPERLINK($J$1&$A10:$A&$J$2&$B10:$B;$J$3)))`
3. In cell I10, insert this formula
   `=arrayformula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($C10:$C;'Geprüfte Ticker'!$C:$P;14;FALSE);""))`

---

This code addresses the **Sheet1** scenario.

The code is technically accurate and will work but there are two other issues the OP may wish to consider.

1. The spreadsheet is "processed daily by several users at the same time". There is a risk that a blank cell that detected in Column A or Column B, and which would be an indicator to delete the while row, is only temporary - the user may intend to correct spelling or enter new data. An "ideal" basis for deleting a row would be to detect a blank cell in both Column A **and ** Column B, but this is not always possible.
2. Even with only test data, recalculation time for the spreadsheet is long - @around 10+ seconds - the time for the live spreadsheet is not known. It's not known what effect this code will have on recalculation.

---

```
    function onEdit(e) {
      // setup spreadsheet and sheet
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var tsName = "onedittest";
      var targetsheet = ss.getSheetByName(tsName);

      // list event data
      // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)); //DEBUG

      //get the formukla ranges and formulas
      // set 1 = Column C-H
      // set 2 = Column N-P
      // Column Q = arrayformula - leave as is
      var rR1 = targetsheet.getRange("C12:H12");
      var fR1 = rR1.getFormulasR1C1();
      var rR2 = targetsheet.getRange("N12:P12");
      var fR2 = rR2.getFormulasR1C1();

      // collect event data
      var editR = e.range.getRow();
      var editRS = e.range.rowStart;
      var editRE = e.range.rowEnd;
      var editC = e.range.getColumn();
      var editCS = e.range.columnStart;
      var editCE = e.range.columnEnd;
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: edited rowstart = "+editRS+", rowend = "+editRE+", columnstart = "+editCS+", columnend = "+editCE);
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: edited row = "+editR+", edited column = "+editC);

      var editedsheet = e.range.getSheet().getSheetName();
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: sheet name = "+editedsheet);

      if (editedsheet === tsName  && editC>= 1 && editC<= 2 && editR>12) {

        // this range/cell is a trigger
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: match");
        var editCell = targetsheet.getRange(editRS, editCS);
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: the edited cell is "+editCell.getA1Notation());
        //Logger.log("DEBUG: the old value = "+e.oldValue+", and the new value = "+e.value);

        //now split Logic#1 and Logic#2
        // Logic#1 = AND there is data in the edited cell (that is, the edit did not make the cell blank), 
        // then copy (or recopy) the formulas from row 12 Columns C-H and N-Q onto the edited row.
        if (editCell.length !=0){
          // copy formulas
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: copy the formulas");
          var formulaset1 = targetsheet.getRange(editRS,3,1,6);
          formulaset1.setFormulasR1C1(fR1);  
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: set formulas for range 1")
          var formulaset2 = targetsheet.getRange(editRS,14,1,3);
          formulaset2.setFormulasR1C1(fR2);  
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: set formulas for range 2")

// Sort the data
      // get the number of rows of data
      var lastheaderRow = 11;
      var Avals = ss.getRange("A12:A").getValues();
      var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: Number of rows of data = "+Alast+", so last row = "+(Alast+lastheaderRow));

      // define the sort range
      var sortRange = targetsheet.getRange(lastheaderRow, 1, Alast+1, 17);
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: the range = "+range.getA1Notation());

      // sort by Column C, ascending
      sortRange.sort({column: 3, ascending: true});

          }
          else{
            // Logic#2 - delete the row
            // Logger.log("DEBUG: delete the row");
            targetsheet.deleteRow(editRS);
          }      
      }
      else
      {
        //not the right sheet, not the column, not the right row
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: do nothing - not matched");    
      }
    }
```

Comment: Note: amended formula for cell J10

Comment: Great work! Thank you very much and sorry for my late answer.